# jquery $.noConflict(); issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented this code into my website (which randomizes/shuffles divs order):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length
    , temporaryValue
    , randomIndex
    ;


  while (0 !== currentIndex) {


    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

$.fn.randomize = function (childElem) {

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var elems = shuffle($(childElem));
        $this.remove(childElem);
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            $this.append(elems[i]);
    }); 
}

jQuery(function($){
    $("div.container").randomize("div.random");
});
```

However it is not working due to conflict with other script, and I assume that $.noConflict(); is the case.

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7L4gu/ i have hard times working it out myself, I will highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of noConflict(), once you use it `$` does not refer to jQuery anymore. In your fiddle the value of `$` undefined once you call `noConflict()` so the expression `$.fn` will fail.

A solution which is widely used is to use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) like

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.randomize = function (childElem) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elems = shuffle($(childElem));
            $this.remove(childElem);
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            $this.append(elems[i]);
        });
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A8Qq8/)

In this case inside the IIFE method we are receiving the jQuery object as an argument and it is named as a local scoped variable `$` so that we can use the shorter form in the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `jQuery.noConflict()`, you can't use `$` outside the `jQuery(function($){...}` block. You need to change `$.fn.randomize = ...` to `jQuery.fn.randomize = ...`, or put the function definition inside the `jQuery` call. You also need to change `$(this)` and `$(childelem)` to `jQuery(this)` and `jQuery(childelem)` inside the `randomize` function.